# ldap client failed to bind to ldap server

Tags: ubuntu, openldap

I have a windows ldap client setup and I have been able to connect to it using the gui ldap admin client. When I try to connect to it using my ubuntu 12.04 client I get the following error in my auth.log:

> Aug 21 16:38:20 uby getent: nss_ldap: failed to bind to LDAP server
>   ldap://pdc.ad.company.com:389: Invalid credentials

Comment: Please read error messages instead of just posting them here and expecting us to do it for you. By posting that line your question answers itself.

Answer (score 1):

`Aug 21 16:38:20 uby getent: nss_ldap: failed to bind to LDAP server ldap://pdc.ad.company.com:389: Invalid credentials`

The "invalid credentials" part means that the credentials your Ubuntu client is using are not valid credentials.  Supply it with correct credentials that have access to read your LDAP directory (or none, if you allow anonymous access), and that should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, do you know what the file it is that I set the user name and password? It use to be some sort of db file in the past.

Comment: @rahrahruby that would really depend on what program you're using to auth against LDAP... which is...?